# Ubuntu takes too long to boot

Tags: boot

I did a dmesg and got  a sudden rise here

```
 [   20.815775] audit: type=1400 audit(1475313340.357:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=1629 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [  102.762235] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
 [  102.762239] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
 [  102.762244] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
 [  106.880349] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
 [  106.896307] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
 [  106.899749] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
 [  107.361522] r8169 0000:13:00.0 eth0: link down
```

Can someone help me to fix it?

Comment: run the following commands and post the output: systemd-analyze systemd-analyze blame systemd-analyze critical-chain A lot many times dmesg includes results for events after the boot process has completed.